# Finding all casimir invariants of a lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Given a semisimple Lie algebra, there is a standard way of obtaining one Casimir invariant using the fact that its Killing form is nondegenerate.

However sometimes there could be another Casimir invariant. For example, the Lie algebra of the Poincare group (not semisimple though) has two Casimir invariants, $P^\mu P_\mu$ and $W^\mu W_\mu$, here $P^\mu$ is the 4 momentum and $W^\mu$ is the Pauli Lubanski vector.

My question is: how to find all Casimir invariants of a Lie algebra? I've also seen statements saying that there are no other Casimir invariants of the Poincare group, how do we prove this?

Comment: This guy: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harish-Chandra_isomorphism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to expand a little on Qiaochu's link, Casimir invariants are exactly elements of the centre of the universal enveloping algebra. In fact they can be viewed as symmetric polynomials in the adjoint representation. We can add or multiply two such polynomials to make new ones of course, so when we talk about "the" Casimir elements we often mean a set that generates this symmetric algebra.

For a reductive Lie algebra of rank $n$ we can find a generating set of $n$ polynomials. As I understand it there is a more constructive proof of this in the case $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, but otherwise the Harish-Chandra isomorphism gets you there.

For the particular case of the Poincare group there are a few discussions of this on the physics stack exchange [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80949/rank-of-the-poincare-group) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/600173/on-poincare-group-s-casimir-operators).